What is the correct ANSI-compatible way to create a pthread from a function with no parameters in C using clang-10+?
I have a function with no parameters in C. Clang-16 suggests me to avoid function declaration without a prototype, but pthread_create does not work anymore with prototype that has no parameters. This is the scenario:
The main.c file tries to create a pthread from a thread_function function:
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "./thread.h"

int main(void) {
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The thread_function function is declared in thread.h header file:
// thread.h
#ifndef _THREAD_H_
#define _THREAD_H_

void *thread_function();

#endif  // _THREAD_H_

And is defined in thread.c file:
// thread.c
#include <stdio.h>

void *thread_function() {
  printf("Hi\n");
  return NULL;
}

I compiled the program with clang-16:
$ clang-16 main.c thread.c -o thread -Wpedantic
In file included from main.c:4:
././thread.h:4:22: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
void *thread_function();
                     ^
                      void
1 warning generated.
thread.c:3:22: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
void *thread_function() {
                     ^
                      void
1 warning generated.

To fix warnings, I applied both suggested fixes:
// thread.h
#ifndef _THREAD_H_
#define _THREAD_H_

void *thread_function(void);

#endif  // _THREAD_H_

And also in thread.c:
// thread.c
#include <stdio.h>

void *thread_function(void) {
  printf("Hi\n");
  return NULL;
}

Now I can not compile the program anymore:
$ clang-16 main.c thread.c -o thread -Wpedantic
main.c:8:36: error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'void *(void)' to parameter of type 'void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable)' [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:334:31: note: passing argument to parameter here
                void * _Nullable (* _Nonnull)(void * _Nullable),
                                            ^
1 error generated.

I changed the signature of the function to:
// thread.h
#ifndef _THREAD_H_
#define _THREAD_H_

void *thread_function(void *);

#endif  // _THREAD_H_

And also:
// thread.c
#include <stdio.h>

void *thread_function(void *) {
  printf("Hi\n");
  return NULL;
}

It compiles then but it is not ANSI-compatible anymore:
$ clang-16 main.c thread.c -o thread -Wpedantic
thread.c:3:29: warning: omitting the parameter name in a function definition is a C2x extension [-Wc2x-extensions]
void *thread_function(void *) {
                            ^
1 warning generated.

If I change the signature to void *thread_function(void *args) it is not "a function with no parameters" anymore. How can I create pthread from a function with no parameters and still be ANSI-compatible?

it is not "a function with no parameters" anymore. Correct. Do you have a special requirement to provide a function that does not match the required type?

What do you mean "ANSI compatible"? There's no ANSI standard for threads afaik. By "ANSI" do you mean C89? Or POSIX?

@Gerhardh The requirement was that providing a function with a dummy parameter produces unused variable warning.

That is not a requirement but a simple fact (depending on the compiler). Do you mean the requirement is to avoid a "unused variable" warning? That can easily be solved without breaking treaties. The API description (that includes the correct function signature) is a treaty you have to follow.

@Lundin You are right! Actually, my assumption about POSIX api for threads was wrong. I did not check the exact argument in man pages. My purpose was writing with exact POSIX standard and having backward compatibility with older C versions.

@Gerhardh Yes, I wanted to avoid using unnecessary variables, but I did not know that the POSIX definition for pthread_create required an argument for the function.

Pthreads have always expected a function pointer of type void* func (void*) regardless of what compiler or C standard you are using. If you ever did anything else, you have been doing it wrong.
void *thread_function(); is an invalid thread callback function in all versions of C and POSIX. Similarly, void *thread_function(void) does not improve anything since it is still the wrong function type.
The last compiler message you get is because a function definition (as opposed to declaration/prototype) without explicit parameter names is nonsense. To be ISO C compatible (forget about "ANSI"), you need to name it:
void *thread_function (void* param)

Now if you aren't passing any parameters to the function you can just cast it to void to disable warnings: (void)param;. Alternatively in upcoming C23, the parameter could be declared as [[maybe_unused]] void* param.

If I change the signature to void *thread_function(void *args) it is not "a function with no parameters" anymore.

It never was. Pthreads demand a function with a void* parameter, period.
What function types to use here is not some option that the programmer can decide. The correct types to use are the ones listed by the library API, man pthread_create:
#include <pthread.h>

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);


As you know perfectly well, void *thread_function(); is not incorrect in C2011 and prior. It declares the function to take an unspecified number of arguments. A program that uses such a function as the start_routine argument to pthread_create is well-formed. Call it bad style if you want, but don't mislead people about what is and isn't valid.

@zwol Like clang said in the OP's question: "a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C ". Yes, C allows you to write all manner of trash programs with non-existent type safety if you insist... indeed you can assign a void* (*) () to a void* (*)(void*) until C23, but that doesn't mean you should.

I never said anyone should do what OP's code does. I only want you to revise your answer to acknowledge the distinction between "OP's code is bad style" and "OP's code is incorrect." In C2011 and prior, the former is true and the latter is not.

If you want to enforce ANSI compatibility with clang, you need to pass either -std=c89 or -ansi.
You can discard an argument explicitly by "casting it to void". Since you absolutely have to name the argument to satisfy -Wpedantic for this to be actually valid C (it's an entirely different story that compilers find parameter name omission acceptable unless e.g. -Wpedantic -Werror. Thanks to John Bollinger for pointing this out), you will have to use this.
void *thread_function(void *arg) {
    (void) arg;
    printf("Hello");
    return NULL;
}

This compiles with -ansi -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror. Compiler explorer link.
Again, the warning regarding unnamed parameters has nothing to do with "ANSI C" specifically. So, use the -ansi or -std=c89 if and only if you know what you're doing and truly require C89/ANSI conformance. Else you probably just want the latest ISO standard supported by your compiler (see man clang and search for -std), or whichever one is used by your team etc.

In a function definition, you have to name all parameters to satisfy the constraints of the C language. If you omit parameter names in a function definition then the result is not valid C, even if you can find a compiler that accepts it.

Ah okay I did not know that. I never omit parameter names myself so was never concerned too deeply about this. I'll edit my answer.


How can I create pthread from a function with no parameters and still be ANSI-compatible?

It is really not that hard, just call your function with a jump function.
void *thread_function() {
  printf("Hi\n");
  return NULL;
}
void *thread_function_jump(void *arg) {
  (void)arg; // To silence some compilers unused arguments warnings.
  printf("Hi\n");
  return thread_function();
}
int main(void) {
  pthread_t thread_id;
  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_function_jump, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Additionally:
#define _THREAD_H_

Is not "compatible". Identifiers starting with _ followed by upper case letter are reserved and we should not be using them. To be compatible, you should change your header guard.

This still gives the unused parameter warning which was the point of the question.

Sorry, the question is what it is. Warnings do not make code ANSI incompatible.
